# String comparison in .NET strange behavior !

Tags: .net

Someone can explain me why this test fails :

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void WierdComparison()
        {
            var machineConf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
            var systemWeb = machineConf.GetSectionGroup("system.web") as SystemWebSectionGroup;
            var prov = systemWeb.Membership.Providers.OfType<ProviderSettings>().Where((s) => s.Name == "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider").First();

            bool result, expected;
            var connectionStringName = prov.ElementInformation.Properties["connectionStringName"].Value;


            result = connectionStringName.Equals("LocalSqlServer");
            expected = true;

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);

            result = connectionStringName == "LocalSqlServer";
            expected = true;

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, result); //This assertion fails
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because you are comparing an `Object` to a `String`.

If you compare two strings, the == operator is overloaded to compare the values of the strings. If you compare an object and a string, the == operator that compares two `Object` references is used, and that simply compares the references, not the values.

The Equals method is a virtual method, so eventhough you call it on an `Object` reference, it will still use the overridden method in the `String` class as the actual type of the object is `String`.

Comment: This is why you should NEVER use the == operator to compare strings. Use String.Compare(), which also lets you use an appropriate culture and do case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: @Jon: You are barking up the wrong tree here, even if it's your favourite tree. ;) The problem here is the use of "var" to declare variables so that you don't clearly see the actual type. Using the == operator works fine as long as you compare string references.